Gradle doesnt list custom repositories
I have recently updated my project to Java21 since one of the dependencies requires it but gradle is now causing issues. I am using ShadowJar + SlimJar to create my uber-jar but I noticed that the original version of ShadowJar doesnt support Java 21 (yet), I found a suitable fork (https://github.com/Goooler/shadow) which does support Java 21. The problem is that the SlimJar plugin im using only supports the original plugin. I tried to adjust the fork to use the fork, and I am hosting it on my maven repo (https://repo.tomkeuper.com/#browse/browse:releases:dev%2Fracci%2Fslimjar) but after trying to include my repo in my settings.gradle.kts and the build.gradle.kts, it doesnt seem to add the to the list of sources.
In the build output you can see the list of used sources and my repo doesnt appear: https://scans.gradle.com/s/dzms363hiz3j6/failure#1
I tried serveral methods of adding my repo to the project but I havent been able to get it to scan it.
Root project settings.gradle.kts / buildSrc settings.gradle.kts
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        maven("https://repo.tomkeuper.com/repository/releases/") // SlimJar
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.tomkeuper.com/repository/releases/'
    }
}

Error in build scan:
Plugin [id: 'dev.racci.slimjar', version: '2.0.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'dev.racci.slimjar:dev.racci.slimjar.gradle.plugin:2.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

The gradle project im trying to add it to: https://github.com/tomkeuper/BedWars2023
I've been trying to get this working for some time now so i'm completely lost atm.
